# What is this space after table float

Tags: tables, spacing, floats, vertical-alignment

I try to tune spacing before and after table float. I've noticed, that there is some space after float, that I can't change.

[image]

Here is same table, but without float.

[image]

And here is the code:

```
\documentclass[oneside,final,14pt]{extreport}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\intextsep}{0pt}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}    
    \lipsum[1]

    \begin{table}[!h]
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
            \hline
            Test & Test \\ \hline
            Test & Test \\ \hline
            Test & Test \\ \hline
            Test & Test \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

How to remove or change this space?

Answer (score 2):

It is just your normal (doubled) line spacing, as you have set the extra space added around floats to 0pt) Without the table table environment the `tabular` acts  like an over-sized letter and does not fit within the specified baseline spacing so at that point TeX gives up and uses `\lineskip` glue (1pt) as a minimum separation.

Comment: Ok, this kind of behaviour I expected. I want to have line spacing after table, but I want to remove \intextsep after it. How to do it normal way? I have only hack way: `\AtEndEnvironment{table}{\vspace{-\intextsep}}`, but it can't determine, if my table inserted into text.

Comment: @noxwell you have set `intextsep` to 0pt so there is nothing to do for `\vspace{-\intextsep}` Consider your table shrunk to zero size, the space you show is the space that would be there anyway, the large inter-line spacing that you have specified.

Comment: I set `intextsep` to zero to show, that there is some space left. In my document I want to actually have equal space before and after table. But I can't tune them independently. Is it possible?